# Can I convert a slice of an array to a different type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, types

I am trying to extract the data of a pixel on a canvas from the ImageData returned by getImageData().

Regardless of whether the following approach is a good idea (I could just convert the entire buffer) I would like to know if it is possible/allowed/advised to just convert a slice of that data.

I tried the following

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("paint");
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
const data = imageData.data;
data[0] = 0x11;
data[1] = 0x22;
data[2] = 0x33;
data[3] = 0x44;
console.log(new Uint32Array(data.slice(0, 4).buffer)[0].toString(16));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="paint" width=500px height=500px />
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I can't really find any documentation on whether this is allowed and what might break in which weird way. Where is type conversion behavior for Javascript documented?
Will this create a copy? Will it access the same memory?

Sorry, if this is a terrible question. I am new to Javascript.

Comment: Interesting question. To answer that one would need to deeply understand how the v8 engine works. I personally found this article rather usefull since it also adresses what happens when we reassign a variable with a new value, which would actually explain part of your question - Article: https://nodeaddons.com/type-conversions-from-javascript-to-c-in-v8/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand MDN docs correctly, this seems safe: [`data.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice) creates a temporal copy of array part, [`new Uint32Array(ArrayBuffer)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Parameters) creates a view for the [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) of this temporal copy. As this temporal copy is not used anywhere else, no data conflict can happen.